# What is the safest way to use API keys in Vue and GC run?

Tags: google-cloud-run, google-cloud-build, google-secret-manager

I have a Vue 3 project that needs to connect to an API. I need to use a private API key in my Vue project. Locally I use environment variables. I'm hosting my Vue project on Google Cloud Run. What's the most secure way to handle secret info on Google Cloud Run?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried [`secret-manager`](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/configuring/secrets) ? Is there any reason for not choosing `secret`manager`?

Comment: Is it a Google Managed API KEY (like Google Maps)? or a third party API KEY?

Comment: @Roopa, my problem with Google's secret manager is that there is no Vue plugin. I failed to convert the official npm package to a Vue plugin.